# d3.js select by id not working. Not sure why not

Tags: d3.js

I'm not sure why this is not working but in my App.tsx I do

```
return(
 <div id="expander">
        <button onClick={handleClick}> This is a button </button>
        <div id="button1">

        </div>
        { clicked && <Visualize name="someName"/>}
</div>
)
```

So I clearly define a div with id of button1

Then in visualize I do

```
var selectDiv=d3.select('#button1')
            var svg = selectDiv.select('svg'),
                inner = svg.select('g');
 var render = new dagreD3.render();
            // // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
            render(inner, g);

 render()
        {
            return (
                <div>
                    <svg className={this.props.name}>
                        <g/>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

The structure of the HTML elements is
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using append for svg and inner.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).